# what does -d 0/0 mean?

Tags: linux, security, firewall, iptables

I came across a rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 17.3.3.5/24 -d 0/0 --dport 22 -j DROP
```

and I was just wondering if someone could explain what this rule is doing. More importantly, I would like to know what the

```
-d 0/0
```

part means, in the whole rule (I know its destination specification, so the 0/0 part should be an IP address, but why is it 0/0?).

Im speculating that the rule is dropping that one source address when it arrives at destination port 22, but I'm not sure.

If someone could explain, that would be great.

Couldn't find an answer when searching the interwebs :C

Comment: It matches any destination. The first 0 is decimal notation for `0.0.0.0`, but that doesn't really matter since the netmask is `/0`

Comment: Thanks @thatotherguy ! so is the rule dropping the IP address 17.3.3.5/24 when it arrives at any destination IP with port 22?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like `-s 17.3.3.5/24` means any source within the CIDR block `17.3.3.5/24`, `-d 0/0` means any destination within the CIDR block `0.0.0.0/0`. Since there are no bits in the network number, every address is inside this network. So it means any destination at all.

Comment: Thanks David!! So just to make sure I understand this, is the rule dropping the IP address 17.3.3.5/24 when it arrives at any destination IP with port 22? (I asked the "other guy above" :D)

Comment: It matches the exact source address 17.3.3.5 and the exact port 22 for inbound traffic. Most likely, it stops that one particular host from reaching a local service on port 22.